# Twig extension function read value

Tags: php, twig, extension-methods

I'm trying to create a set of simplified functions to let an user create a twig template that will be rendered as a form.

The form, when executed should read self generated data array.

The code below should print a field with name 'hello', when submitted (with example value 'world') create an array key hello and display the binded field with value 'world'.

Example template:

```
  {{configkey('hello', 'Hello Field')}}
```

The extension function

```
    $func = new Twig_SimpleFunction('configkey', function ($key='example', $label='label') {

        echo  '<div class="control-group">';
        echo  '<label class="control-label" for="' . $key . '">' . $label . '</label>';
        echo  '<div class="controls">';
        echo  '<input type="text" name="' . $key . '" value="{{config.' . $key . '}}"/>';
        echo  '</div>';
        echo  '</div>';

    });
```

$this->_twigEnv->addFunction('configkey',$func);

the output

[image: the undesired output]

Comment: twig function should not echo result, it has to return result

Comment: instead of echo the html embed that in a twig files and so you can print correctly the config array value. Are you using the Twig component standalone or inside a framework? I can suggest you an implementation based on symfony2 framework. Let me know

Comment: @kmlnvm I tried briefly to return a string but the function outputs a raw html.
I'm in a zf1 application with custom zend view relying on twig with a custom implementation of twig loader to pull templates from S3.

Answer (score 0):

Thakns everyone for help but i found the solution easier than expected..

```
 $func = new Twig_SimpleFunction('configkey', function ($key='example', $label='label', $value='') {

    echo  '<div class="control-group">';
    echo  '<label class="control-label" for="' . $key . '">' . $label . '</label>';
    echo  '<div class="controls">';
    echo  '<input type="text" name="' . $key . '" value="' . $value . '"/>';
    echo  '</div>';
    echo  '</div>';

});
```

The call will be

```
{{configkey('hello', 'Hello Field', config.hello)}}
```

Do you have a better aproach for the binding just using the key parameter ?